# extjs bind parent's bindable property to child's

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a container with one or more form fields in it. I would like to bind the `hidden` property of the parent container to the `disabled` property of the child items
How do we do this?

I have a fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34dg) to illustrate. I have fields in my optional container that are required. So when visible, they should be required, when hidden they should be optional. I know that I can add a handler that can set `allowBlank: true` but that seems tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register parent's hidden state in viewModel to get parents state in child component.

change "containerHidden" property in viewModel to true or false to test it.
 [here is fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34er)

```js
viewModel:{
    data:{
        containerHidden:true
    }
},
defaults: {
    labelAlign: "right"
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: "textfield",
        fieldLabel: "Name",
        allowBlank: false
    },
    {
        xtype: "datefield",
        fieldLabel: "Date of Birth",
        emptyText: "18+ gets more options",
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: {
            change: "onDoBChange"
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: "container",
        reference: "AgeRestrictedArea",
        bind:{
            hidden:"{containerHidden}"
        },
        defaults: {
            labelAlign: "right"
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: "textfield",
                fieldLabel: "Hobby",
                allowBlank:false,
                bind:{
                    disabled: "{containerHidden}"
                }

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: this does not work. return the previous option) with `formulas`.

Comment: what do you mean by not working? do you mean the code here or the fiddle? the form is valid in container's both state. can you please tell me what is not working exactly?

Comment: code and fiddle dont work. try set value in datefield on 18 years old https://i.imgur.com/9ulHmPE.png

Comment: form is valid because hobby in init state hobby field is disabled, but  state don't change where changed visible on container

Comment: my falt sorry, didnot notised  me.lookup("AgeRestrictedArea").setHidden(); this line :)) now it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209570/discussion-between-pvlt-and-lightnight).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help hide\show listeners [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34eq)